# JSonKit deserialization problem

Tags: iphone, ios, json

I have JSON as NSString:

```
[{"bus_number":"1","created_at":"2011-08-15T23:07:52Z","id":1,"model":"Setra","registar_number":"123456","seats":50,"tour_id":1,"updated_at":"2011-08-15T23:07:52Z"},{"bus_number":"2","created_at":"2011-08-15T23:07:52Z","id":2,"model":"Mercedes","registar_number":"2234","seats":60,"tour_id":1,"updated_at":"2011-08-15T23:07:52Z"}]
```

and I'm trying to convert this NSString to NSDictionary.

When I use:

```
NSDictionary *sourceDictionary = [[response bodyAsString] objectFromJSONString];
```

I get NSDictionary like this:

```
(
    {
    "bus_number" = 1;
    "created_at" = "2011-08-15T23:07:52Z";
    id = 1;
    model = Setra;
    "registar_number" = 123456;
    seats = 50;
    "tour_id" = 1;
    "updated_at" = "2011-08-15T23:07:52Z";
},
    {
    "bus_number" = 2;
    "created_at" = "2011-08-15T23:07:52Z";
    id = 2;
    model = Mercedes;
    "registar_number" = 2234;
    seats = 60;
    "tour_id" = 1;
    "updated_at" = "2011-08-15T23:07:52Z";
}
```

)

but, there is a problem with this NSDictionary, I can't access to their elements, some elements aren't NSStrings (like model).

**How to convert JSONString to NSDictionary with NSStrings?**

**EDIT:**

When I try to Log in console this with:

```
for (id key in sourceDictionary) {
            NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [sourceDictionary objectForKey:key]);
        }
```

I get exception:

```
-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c3a50
```

Comment: You are not getting an NSDictionary with this line `NSDictionary *sourceDictionary = [[response bodyAsString] objectFromJSONString];`, you are getting an NSArray

Comment: How? Object class is NSDictionary :-o

Comment: `objectFromJSONString` returns id, in this case it can return either an NSArray or an NSDictionary. Just because you chose to declare your variable as `NSDictionary *sourceDictionary` doesn't mean it will be a dictionary. There are two proofs on your post to this: A) The exception (where it says that sourceDictionary it's actually an array). B) The "dictionary" you got has two objects, but no keys for those objects, because it's actually an array ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are actually NSStrings, they just don't have quotation marks when you print them out to the console.

Comment: Why for example "registar_number" have quotation marks but model doesn't?

Comment: Usually if it's only letters (no other symbols) it will be shown without quotes.

Comment: Thx for answer. I just edited question, why then I getting this error? This loop should work on any NSDictionary with NSStrings

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting this from RestKit, and it looks like you are, you can just do this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [response.body mutableObjectFromJSONData];
```

This way, you're pulling in the raw the binary data and you can avoid some unnecessary (and costly) conversions back and forth to strings in the process.  Also, I stipulated mutable, because chances are you'll want to manipulate or muck about with the data when you get it ... again, there are costs involved in conversions between non-mutable and mutable objects from the JSONKit superclasses ... so by going with mutable from the outset, you just saved yourself some time.